# regex to get different matches

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

This is my output:

```
CASE 1:
---------------------------------- 
Drop Pack: FALSE 
Drop Flow: FALSE 
---------------------------------- 
CASE 2:
---------------------------------- 
Drop Flow: TRUE 
Fail Open: FALSE 
Fail Close: FALSE 
---------------------------------- 
CASE 3:
---------------------------------- 
Drop Flow: FALSE
```

I need a regex to match values as below:

regex 1: to get only the first match as below

```
 Drop Flow: FALSE (UNDER CASE1)
```

regex 2: to get only the second match as below:

```
 Drop Flow: TRUE (UNDER CASE2)
```

The regex I have is:

```
Drop Flows:\s+([A-Z]+)
```

But this gives all the 3 matches (case 1 , case2 and case3). How can I get individual matches?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/bPrNPK/1 Which environment or language you are using?

Comment: Robot framework

Answer (score 1):

Try it as suggested:

```
(CASE \d+)(?:(?!CASE \d+)[\s\S])*(Drop Flow: (?:TRUE|FALSE))
```

- The pattern starts searching the head anchor using `CASE \d+` and puts it in `$1`,
- consumes everything that does not contain this very string `(?:(?!CASE \d+)[\s\S])*` to avoid grabbing the Drop Flow value from another CASE,
- and finally, searches the end anchor `(Drop Flow: (?:TRUE|FALSE))` and puts it in `$2`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bPrNPK/1)

Some Python code along that lines:

```
import re
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print ("Group {groupNum}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first 2 matches and not the third on, you can add a positive lookahead `(?=\s*\r?\n\S)` that asserts that there should be a line following that starts with a non whitespace char `\S`

```
Drop Flow:\s+([A-Z]+)(?=\s*\r?\n\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zbjGh/1)

Another option is to capture the value in group 1, and the TRUE FALSE part in group 2 and make sure there is a closing line that starts with a hyphen.

```
^CASE \d+:\r?\n-+[^\S\r\n]*(?:\r?\n(?!Drop Flow:).*)*\r?\n(Drop Flow: (TRUE|FALSE))[^\S\r\n]*(?:\r?\n(?!-).*)*\r?\n-
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NxJQAx/1)